# How to find the difference between tow days in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch we have events per day. Some events occurring over multiple days. Now I wanna find out on which day certain events are dropping out.

Day1:

- Event1
- Event2
- Event3

Day2:

- Event1
- Event2

At the end of Day2 I want to get all events which dropped out in comparison to the previous day (Day1). The result should show the difference on event level (document level), so no aggregation.

Result:

- Event3

Is it possible to achieve this with ES in general?

Comment: writing a code and doing there pro-grammatically should be preferred.